# Creating a defconfig for u-boot

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, sabre

I'm trying to create a defconfig for u-boot using make u-boot-savedefconfig but I get the error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'u-boot-savedefconfig'.  Stop.make: *** No rule to make target 'u-boot-savedefconfig'.  Stop.
```

Should I modify the makefile or is it not possible to create a defconfig for u-boot?

I expect a defconfig file to be created using the existing .config file as I'd like to upload the defconfig to github.

Are there any docs that I can follow? I'm using timesys to create custom embedded Linux, the docs in Timesys do not contain any info about creating defconfig.

Comment: What specific information do you need? I'm trying to compile it so the only code I use is make! would it be helpful if I provide a copy of the Makefile?

Comment: Likely the best way to make a defconfig is to copy and modify the closest existing one...

Answer (score 1):

The name of the make target is not **u-boot-savedefconfig** but just **savedefconfig** just like the Linux kernel.

Comment: Does this create a defconfig for kernel u-boot and rootfs or is it just for u-boot?

Comment: Also there is a makefile in the u-boot directory, would it be better to run make savedefconfig there?

Comment: Your initial question is very unclear.  In U-Boot, to make a defconfig for U-Boot, you do what I said.  If you're using buildroot, which it sounds like maybe you are, you would need to configure buildroot to use the config for U-Boot that you made and that would be another different question.

Comment: Thank you for the support Mr Tom Rini. I've followed what you said and it did create a defconfig file can this file be used to generate a .config file using make defconfig?

Comment: Yes, that "defconfig" file will work in U-Boot, just like a "defconfig" file in the Linux Kernel works.  All values that are the default are removed from the file.